# Can't Restart Tor

Tags: mac

I can't use Tor Browser. Keep getting a message that Tor needs to be restarted to reach websites. When I click the Restart Tor button, the same message box keeps coming back up. At the bottom of box there is a button to Copy Tor Log to Clipboard with an email for Tor support email addy. Also a Continue button. Nothing seems to work. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling, keep getting the same problems. I use a Mac with Mavericks OS. 
Please, any suggestions.

Comment: An update: I just opened Tor Browser and the same thing happens as above. Although this time I put on Activity Monitor to see what the CPU is doing, and discovered that a file (or process) called tor.real has been running in the background for many many hours, that is, some Tor process has been running constantly when the computer is awake. This process does not stop even when close Tor Browser. What is happening? Something is definitely gone haywire. I run Mavericks on an iMac.